# Python implied path works on XP but not windows 7

Tags: python, windows, relative-path

I am learning to use Python and tkinter as a hobby.

I have two systems at different locations: one is XP (SP3) and the other is Win7 (SP1).

The code snippet for this question is as follows:

```
import tkinter
import sys
print (sys.path)
wnd = tkinter.Tk()
wnd.title("Sinewave's window")
wnd.geometry("250x100+10+30")

#this one works in both XP and Windows7
wnd.wm_iconbitmap('C:\Python34\icons\colours.ico')

#this one works in XP but not in windows 7
#wnd.wm_iconbitmap('./icons/colours.ico') #implied path

wnd.mainloop()
```

The shell window shows the path as:

```
['C:/Python34/py scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\py scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The error when I try the "implied" path in Win7 is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "./icons/colours.ico" not defined
```

I have tried many variations but cannot get the "implied" path to work in Win7.

Am I missing something, or does it just not work like in XP ?

(Of course, to try out this snippet you must create the folder "icons" and define an  appropriate icon).

Answer (score 1):

For loading files, the relative path is not relative to `sys.path` , it should be relative to your current working directory.

`sys.path` is used when python imports modules , its not used for loading files or for tkinter.

For file openning and all only the current working directory is considered (unless you have given complete aboslute path).

So the issue must be occuring in Windows 7 , because there may not be a `icons/colours.ico` file relative to the directory from which you run the script. It may be present in case of Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Actually I got caught up in my own (misplaced) enthusiasm, but you did point me in the right direction. Between the "working" XP version and the "not working" win7 version I had re-arranged a few folders. I moved the python scripts into their own folder below the "python34" folder. Now the "icons" folder and the "scripts" folder are on the same level below the "python34" folder. So the "fix" in my code snippet is: wnd.wm_iconbitmap('../icons/colours.ico') - note the extra dot before ./icons - it now works properly.

Comment: Also, `..` means to go to parent directory , for anyone who did not know.